# How do I remove the (superflous) left range endpoint added to bin labels created by base::cut()?

Tags: r, categories, binning

This data

```
> seq(0,1,0.1) -> x
> x
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

can be binned quite well into categories with labels that are illustrative for my application, but it seems that I cannot get rid of an extra (and not needed?) left range endpoint introduced by the function, for some reason:

```
> cut(x,breaks = 10,include.lowest = TRUE,right = TRUE,dig.lab=1)
 [1] [-0.001,0.1] [-0.001,0.1] (0.1,0.2]    (0.2,0.3]    (0.3,0.4]    (0.4,0.5]    (0.5,0.6]   
 [8] (0.6,0.7]    (0.7,0.8]    (0.8,0.9]    (0.9,1]     
10 Levels: [-0.001,0.1] (0.1,0.2] (0.2,0.3] (0.3,0.4] (0.4,0.5] (0.5,0.6] (0.6,0.7] ... (0.9,1]
> cut(x,breaks = 10,include.lowest = TRUE,right = FALSE,dig.lab=1)
 [1] [-0.001,0.1) [0.1,0.2)    [0.2,0.3)    [0.3,0.4)    [0.4,0.5)    [0.5,0.6)    [0.6,0.7)   
 [8] [0.7,0.8)    [0.8,0.9)    [0.9,1]      [0.9,1]     
10 Levels: [-0.001,0.1) [0.1,0.2) [0.2,0.3) [0.3,0.4) [0.4,0.5) [0.5,0.6) [0.6,0.7) ... [0.9,1]
> cut(x,breaks = 10,include.lowest = FALSE,right = TRUE,dig.lab=1)
 [1] (-0.001,0.1] (-0.001,0.1] (0.1,0.2]    (0.2,0.3]    (0.3,0.4]    (0.4,0.5]    (0.5,0.6]   
 [8] (0.6,0.7]    (0.7,0.8]    (0.8,0.9]    (0.9,1]     
10 Levels: (-0.001,0.1] (0.1,0.2] (0.2,0.3] (0.3,0.4] (0.4,0.5] (0.5,0.6] (0.6,0.7] ... (0.9,1]
> cut(x,breaks = 10,include.lowest = FALSE,right = FALSE,dig.lab=1)
 [1] [-0.001,0.1) [0.1,0.2)    [0.2,0.3)    [0.3,0.4)    [0.4,0.5)    [0.5,0.6)    [0.6,0.7)   
 [8] [0.7,0.8)    [0.8,0.9)    [0.9,1)      [0.9,1)     
10 Levels: [-0.001,0.1) [0.1,0.2) [0.2,0.3) [0.3,0.4) [0.4,0.5) [0.5,0.6) [0.6,0.7) ... [0.9,1)
```

For me, and my data, I cannot see why the range of the first category is said to include also the -0.0001 that doesn't exist in the data.

Any ideas? Why not simply "[0-0.1]"?

Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in the [manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut), and it's somewhat logic when you think about it (my emphasis):

> When breaks is specified as a single number, the range of the data is
> divided into breaks pieces of equal length, **and then the outer limits
> are moved away by 0.1% of the range** to ensure that the extreme values
> both fall within the break intervals.

Now, if you debug the cut function, and step through it:

```
> debug( base:::cut.default )
```

You will see that not only the low end, but also the high end does this. The effective numerical breaks in use are:

```
Browse[2]> breaks
 [1] -0.001  0.100  0.200  0.300  0.400  0.500  0.600  0.700  0.800  0.900  1.001
Browse[2]> ch.br
 [1] "-0.001" "0.1"    "0.2"    "0.3"    "0.4"    "0.5"    "0.6"    "0.7"    "0.8"    "0.9"    "1"
```

The real question you are asking, is why do I see that extra `.001` thingy just on one end, and not the other?

Well if you look back at the cut.default code, you will see it uses formatC to do the work:

`ch.br <- formatC(0 + breaks, digits = dig, width = 1L)`

Now consider this:

```
> formatC( c(-0.001, 1.001), digits=1, width=1 )
[1] "-0.001" "1"
```

I don't know why formatC does this. base::formatC in the end does `.Internal(formatC(x, as.character(mode), width, digits, as.character(format), flag, i.strlen)` and at this point I stopped digging.

You cold *easily* roll your own `cut()` functon that doesn't use `formatC`. It should probably still add interval left and right, but it needn't show in the labels, which is the real problem here. Just grab the code in base:::cut.default and swap those few lines necessary (and ideally publish it afterwards)

Otherwise, I don't think `cut` is being used most (that would explain why this inconsistency lingers today)

If you re-do your range from 1 to 2 instead, you will see what you expect to see.